# Filtering database base on a drop-down list that populating from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to filter some data from MySQL database base on a drop-down list that populating from the MySQL database.

Now I have got a drop-down list like this:

[image: drop-down list]

which is populating from the MySQL database:
[image: MySQL database]
The following are my code for the drop-down list:

```
      <?php
  $result2 = $conn->query("select id, field from customer_details GROUP BY field");
  echo "<select id='sf' name='id'>";
  echo '<option value="">Show All</option>';
  while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($id, $field);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $field = $row['field']; 
    echo '<option value = "'.$id.'">'.$field.'</option>';
  }
  echo "</select>";
  ?>
```

Does anyone know how can I get the selected text of the drop-down menu?
I have tried to use `$_POST[]` in different ways like `$_POST['id']`

```
      <?php
  $result2 = $conn->query("select id, field from customer_details GROUP BY field");
  echo "<select id='sf' name='id'>";
  echo '<option value="">Show All</option>';
  while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($id, $field);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $field = $row['field']; 
    echo '<option value = "'.$id.'">'.$field.'</option>';
  }
  echo "</select>";
  echo $_POST['id'];
  ?>
```

then Notice pop up from the website:
Notice: Undefined index: id
What should I do?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and welcome to SO.

Comment: Are you using a `form` or how is this being submitted?

Comment: And be careful with words like 'field' - strangely it's not even acknowledged as a keyword in the documentation, but it is a function name, and could be reserved in the future.

Comment: Try https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html